# How to find solution of a equation in n+1 variables so as to find extremal points

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, rational-functions

Need help in finding maxima of a function . 
[image]

> assume $x_1$ , $x_2$ ,...,$x_{n+1}$ all belong to [0, 1] .

assume r to be any positive integer -> 
Then what are the solutions of equation.

> r- $\frac{ x_l}{1-x_l} $+ (2r+1)× $\frac{ x_1× x_2× ... × x_{n+1} } { 1-x_{1}× x_{2} ×  x_{n+1} }$ =0.

Edit 1 ->  So, the question is prove that the maximum occurs at the diagonal $x_{1}$ = $x_{2}$ = ... =$x_{a+1} $ .

Comment: @Alexander what's wrong with this question ?

Comment: At the time I closed it, the equation you asked about wasn't an equation. Can you type the math parts in MathJax, and also include a couple details about its context within the paper?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber  that  will make it complex, additionally details are not needed. Question is complete in itself. Kindly reopen it!

Comment: A link to the paper would suffice. The MathJax portion is just for readability.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I don't know how to add links of papers . I added the name of paper and fixed mathjax as much I know. I hope it's fine now. Can you please reopen it.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference you link papers like this: `[text](url)`. For example [Google](https://www.google.com) is `[Google](https://www.google.com)`

Comment: @TimGreen You can only consider $x_l\in (0, 1), \forall l$ since if one $x_l=0$ etc, then $F=0$. From the equations, you have $\frac{x_i}{1-x_i} = \frac{x_j}{1-x_j}$ for any $i < j$.

Comment: @RiverLi solving the equation which you wrote I got the answer as $ x_{1} $ = ... = $ x_{l} $. So, it s easy. Hope I am not doing any mistake? Asking as its now seems very easy!!

Comment: @TimGreen Yes, $x_1 = x_2= \cdots = x_{a+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that this is useful for your questions.

For system of equation, you can deduce that $\frac{x_i}{1-x_i}=\frac{x_j}{1-x_j}$ for all $1 \leq i,j\leq n+1$ so $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j$.

For finding argmax by taking derivative. Since the objective function will be $0$ if any $x_i=0$ or $x_i=1$ (of course we need to assume that $\prod x_i <1$). So we just need to solve the maximization problem under open set $(0,1)^{n+1}$ which has the necessary condition is that the derivative equals to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You would expect to be able to pick $n$ of the variables over some range and calculate the last one.  There is not necessarily a nice description of the range for each, as it depends on the other ones.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: author write that the maximum is reached at diagonal $x_1$ , $x_2$ ,  ... $x_{a+1}$ . I don't know how they deduced it.

Comment: When you have more equations than unknowns you can typically specify a number of the unknowns freely over a range, then solve for as many as you have equations.  That applies here.  If you let $n=1$ you should be able to see how you could solve the equation for either $x_1$ or $x_2$ given $r$ and the other one.  You might not come out in the range $[0,1]$, which limits the range you can choose the first over.

Comment: I am sorry, there was typo in my earlier comment, maximum occurs at diagonal at $x_{1} $ = $x_{2} $ =... = $ x_{a+1}$.Certainly , your comment was helpful but I am unable to prove all of them equal as solution of inequality and that too only solution.

Comment: so it is to be prove that equality of $x_{i} $ is only solution of the equation.

Comment: Nowhere do you ask about the maximum.  What expression are you trying to maximize?  If they all equal $1$ the last term in your equation is undefined.  You ask about solving the equation and I have said you can solve for any one variable you would like.  If you are not solving for $x_1$ the equation is linear and you can solve it by the usual technique of clear fractions, isolate the terms containing that variable on one side, use the distributive property and divide.  It is quadratic in $x_1$.

Comment: I meant to say prove that only solution of above equation is $x_{1}$ =$x_{2}$= ... $x_{i}$.Also note thar actually this equation in question is first derivative of the equation I want to maximimize. I by mistake wrote it here in comment.

Comment: I tried again putting all $x_{i} $ except $x_{l} $ equal to 0 . So, I got $x_l$ = r/( r+1) . So, there exists another solution. But in the paper all $x_{i} $ are equal is only solution. I am adding image. Can you please look at it if you have some spare time.

Comment: I have added bounty, in case you want to answer it now or others can answer it.

Comment: You have missed the point that there are $n+1$ equations, one for each of the $x$ variables.  Now there are enough equations to solve it.  The maximum is the maximum of $F$, which never appears in your question.  Please make sure to include all the relevant information when posting a question.  The text uses $l$ as a subscript, which can look like $1$

Comment: I deeply regret for inconvenience caused but i had no idea that it would cause such confusion as I would never  cause situations which will make my chances less for answers.

Comment: can you please help me ?